# how do I add a second parameter to the tags in acts_as_taggable_on_steroids plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, acts-as-taggable-on-ster

In my Rails application I am trying to use the acts_as_taggable_on_steroids plugin but it is falling short a little bit. I would like to add a second parameter to each tag that describes what it is tagging. Not the class, I understand that is recorded in the taggings join table. For example, if I were to tag an interview, I would give it multiple tags in the form of ("microsoft","company"), ("campus", "location"). Currently the only way to add tags to an item  is with `Model.tag_list.add(*args)`. Would it be easier for me to modify the plugin or to start from the ground up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that I am going to switch out acts-as-taggable-on-steroids for acts-as-taggable-on which has something called context tagging.